# Ubuntu 20.04: keys don't work when I am on the Desktop (outside File Manager)

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, keys

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. When I am outside the File Manager/File Browser/Files, none of the arrow keys, delete keys, etc. work. They all start working once I am working inside the File Manager. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the default desktop environment of Ubuntu 20.04 has this innate problem. One solution is installing alternate desktop environments that do not have this problem, e.g. Cinnamon.

In Cinnamon, I can easily navigate using the arrow keys on the Desktop itself. See this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/SToy_OXS45U) for more details.